# Greatest Common Divisor - Programming Question

Tags: logic, gcd-and-lcm, programming

You are given a number $g$. Find a sequence $A$ of length $n$ which satisfies the following condition:

1. $GCD ( A_0, A_1, A_2, .... ,A_i, ..... ,A_{n-1} ) = g.$
2. $A_i > g, \ 0 \le i < n.$
3. $A_i \ge A_j,\ \forall j \le i$
4. Define a function, $sum(A) = A_0 + A_1 + .... + A_{n-1}.$

If multiple sequences satisfy the first three properties, print the one which minimizes $sum(A)$ function.

---

**This is the program I wrote:**

int g=0, n=0;

cin>>g>>n;

n += 2;

for(int j = 2; j< n; j++)

cout<< g*j<<" ";

---

It's incorrect, did I understood the question wrong. Or, can anybody explain to me the right logic?

**Edit:**
I love math

---

The above program will become.,

int g=0, n=0;

cin>>g>>n;

cout<< g*(2n+1) << endl;

Comment: The beginning is okay. Can you give me the best possible value for $a_2$?

Comment: @Mindlack what do you mean by `a2`?

Comment: I meant $A_2$..

Comment: I've got an example., for g = 1 and n = 2, the sequence A of length 2 is., 2 3

Comment: Ok, what about $n=3$?

Comment: That would be -- 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

Comment: Sure? You can do better for the last four terms.

Comment: Right -- 2, 2, 2, 2, 3?

Comment: That’s better indeed. I don’t think this can be improved now.

Comment: Optimized. Cool, Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the GCD is pairwise $g$ or that the GCD of all the numbers together is $g$?  Consider $6,10,15$, which has GCD of $1$ but each pair has a higher GCD.

Comment: @RossMillikan Nope, I mean GCD all together, and if there are multiple solutions, then the one with the lowest sum, _sum(A)_.

Comment: So the lowest sum is (2n+1)*g ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Yup.